# Critical Infrastructure Language Selection

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architecture, real-time

I took over a development team working on life-safety critical software earlier in the year. The product has been in development for about 8 years, but the current team has only been working on the product for about 2 years. I’m not a software engineer by trade, but have been a system administrator for a ~300 person org in the past, so I rely heavily on the team to make the right decisions and explain to me what those are and why.

The product is designed to be highly available and modular; the front end is written in JavaScript (which I am biased against from some of my previous experiences), and the backend is written in a mix of C/C++, Python, and JavaScript in a microservice architecture.

My question: I remember from the ‘90’s and early 2000’s there were flame wars about using Java on the server, and if that was the right option because Garbage Collection introduces potential for resource spikes or lags (not that it ever stopped IBM or HP). Is this still a concern running interpreted, garbage collected languages on the server? What about for time-critical life safety systems? Our software is all designed to run on x86 with a timesharing OS anyway, so we aren’t “real time” like an embedded application could be, but what is the current thinking in this area?

The phrase “time critical” in this context means losing more than 500ms wall time to some sort of resource conflict is a failure of the product

Comment: If you have _hard_ real time deadlines, you cannot use a timesharing OS. You never know when the OS is going to do something you don't expect.

Comment: Are you considering introducing Java to the server-side?  You mention JavaScript but that (most likely) isn't running on a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).  I'm asking because you mention you are not a SE and it's common and understandable to be confused about the relationship between Java and JS.

Comment: @JimmyJames sorry no, that was just an example from the last time I had to look at something like this (late 90’s). I’m looking to get caught up on the most current thinking

Comment: GC pauses are still a concern, but they're not a problem. Typical JVMs let you choose from different GC algorithms and let you tune parameter to get your desired tradeoff between pause times, throughput, and memory usage. It's really not a problem for the typical microservice system, you'll just see occasional latency spikes. Personally, I'd be more concerned about preventing and detecting safety-relevant bugs. Old-school JS, Python, and C/C++ make it difficult to write safe and correct software, but modern TypeScript and Python's typing help a lot. Rust is also nice for C++-style use cases.

Comment: I will just address the FE JS part, unless you are writing a native app for a specific piece of hardware, you will be using something that has its layers of abstractions and unpredictability on the client.
If the FE is mainly a UI for sending network request (i.e. does not do any real processing of its own other than rendering "simple" data (no fancy 3d stuff) and reacting to user interaction events), then it is irrelevant what tech you are using on the FE as any latency is more likely to be a result of network/server issues than FE performance.

Comment: Slight correction on the "simple" data: Rendering can become an issue if you have a lot going on the screen of a weak device even if 2d and the "only" dynamic part being scrolling. However, this issue can happen on any FE solution and JS has a plethora of solutions how to approach those situations as it is a common issue on browsers

Answer (score 7):

The choice of language isn't really that important in your scenario. You need to look at the architecture as a whole to see whether it can meet the requirements (and maybe you need to look at the requirements to see whether they are just arbitrarily invented because someone "feels" that 500ms is the limit, or truly important for the working of the system such as a braking assistant which simply must react within a few ms to prevent deadly accidents).

Whenever you're using shared resources (timesharing OS, network infrastructure, managed memory) you will have unpredictable timing effects. Normally the requirements for such systems are expressed as percentiles and not hard limits, for example at least 98% of requests should be answered in less than 500ms. However, these depend as much on the data and usage pattern as they depend on the software system.

Answer (score 5):

> My question: I remember from the ‘90’s and early 2000’s there were flame wars about using Java on the server, and if that was the right option because Garbage Collection introduces potential for resource spikes or lags (not that it ever stopped IBM or HP). Is this still a concern running interpreted, garbage collected languages on the server?

Garbage Collection (GC) can absolutely cause pauses on the server.  I've seen multi-second pauses in production applications.  This is a complex topic and especially so with Java because there are so many options for runtimes, and within each there can be multiple garbage collector implementations, and options for those collectors.  It's not inevitable that you will have these issues.  In fact, there's a company that claims to have a [pause-less GC for Java](https://www.azul.com/products/components/pgc/).  (As an aside, watching presentations by one of the founders: Gil Tene has taught me more about GC than any other source.)

There's too much ground to cover but the upshot is that if you have GC pauses in Java, you can almost always eliminate them through tuning the GC or using a different collector.  The default collector (G1) in most contemporary Java runtimes is a lot better than what was available 20 years ago as well.

That said, it's not clear that this is relevant to your situation.  Of the languages you mentioned, JavaScript and Python are expected to be garbage collected.  I don't have any experience with server-side JavaScript (I've never understood the appeal of doing this) but this isn't an issue I associate with Python.  The main way that Python (CPYthon) collects garbage is different than Java and while theoretically flawed (i.e., it needs a Java-style collector for certain situations) in practice, it tends to work very well.

I did a little poking around on JavaScript and if the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) is correct about "Currently, all modern engines ship a mark-and-sweep garbage collector." there might be some risk of long pauses.  I don't see a lot of complaints about that, but it might be worth more research.  In Java the 'mark-and-sweep' collection is typically when you see pauses and what I saw suggests that JS engines may lack the mitigating early generation copy-collector that even older Java GCs support.

One of challenges with GC pauses is that you can have a situation where your app runs without any significant pauses for days, even weeks, and then suddenly you get a horribly long pause.  A fairly simple solution for that is to restart regularly.  If you are running these in containers, you could, in theory, run with a no-op garbage collector and use container restarts as your GC solution.  It might seem hacky to restart every night (or whatever) but it's actually kind of smart.  Apps that restart regularly are known to be able to restart reliably.  An app that runs for months or even years might not restart properly after a crash.

Comment: All major modern JS engines ([V8](https://v8.dev/blog/high-performance-cpp-gc), [JSC](https://webkit.org/blog/12967/understanding-gc-in-jsc-from-scratch/), [SpiderMonkey](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/js/gc.html)) use a generational garbage collector, often combined with other approaches. Pauses can happen, but are rarely long, as people don't like browsers where game animations are glitching :-)

Comment: "The main way that Python collects garbage is very different than Java" – Can you give some detail on this? I am not an expert in either Python or Java, but to my understanding, the way that Python collects garbage is *exactly identical* to Java, namely that neither Python nor Java specify in any way, shape, or way, how memory is managed and different implementations compete on this subject. For example, IBM's Metronome, Azul's CCC, PyPy's incminimark, etc. JNode's MMtk is specifically designed to be able to implement all sorts of different GC algorithms, from simple reference counting to …

Comment: … highly sophisticated hybrids of reference counting, monadic regions, and tracing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, You're right, the Python language doesn't specify how memory is managed. However, the by far dominant implementation, CPython, [uses reference counting](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html?highlight=garbage%20collection#how-does-python-manage-memory), while all the major Java implementations have more advanced (and efficient) garbage collection. I assume this is what JimmyJames means.

Comment: @Vaelus Yes, the reference counting in CPython is what I meant.  I should have qualified that.  As I understand it, CPython also has mark-sweep (or something that can clear cycles but it doesn't need to do much in a typical application because the reference counting will find most garbage.

Comment: @Bergi I read somewhere that JS collectors were (typically) non-generational but it was probably outdated and I'll take your word for it.  Are those typically the engines used on the server-side?  My (pretty limited) experience with JS has been almost entirely browser-based.

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes, nodejs (the poster child of server-side js) runs on V8. Other engines are used as well in some popular runtimes, but I don't know any hard numbers

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are going to lose half a second to garbage collection in any normal usage with c#/java

However, language selection generally isn't a choice you can just make. It's made for you by your history and current employee experience. It does sounds like you have a bit of a mishmash of a tech stack and could use some sort of direction in this space, but you are going to have to ask hard questions like:

- "Will i have to sack half the people here and hire java devs?"
- "How long will it take to switch tech, can I really have no new features for that long?"
- "How long will I have to run with twice as many devs, half supporting the old system and half writing the new system?"

Comment: These are good considerations for project/team management, definitely. I’m asking for the technical analysis of language/framework choice (sorry if not clear)

Comment: technically they are all turing complete. Maybe with a tonne of detail on your particular problem one choice would come out ahead. But it makes no difference if you can't actually implement the change

Comment: @agentroadkill it is too late to do basic analysis like this 8 years in development.